# SCSS mixin add percentage fails

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I have a SCSS mixin with the below definition for `linear-gradient`.

```
@mixin custom-background(
  $color: $color,
  $progress: 0
) {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, $color #{$progress}%, #9EC9DB 0);
  border: #10516C solid #9EC9DB;
}
```

But on compiling with `gulp-sass` it breaks with below error:

> Error: Invalid CSS after "... #{$progress} %": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ", $progress-"
>           on line 15 of file.scss
>
> > nt(to right, $color #{$progress} %, #9EC9DB 0);
> >        ------------------------------------------^
>
> messageOriginal: Invalid CSS after "... #{$progress} %": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ", $color"

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation is for different purposes, like creating a selector from a string variable. Not to convert values. To convert a number to percentages, simply multiply it by `100%`.

```
@mixin custom-background(
  $color: $color,
  $progress: 0
) {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, $color $progress * 100%, #9EC9DB 0);
  border: #10516C solid #9EC9DB;
}
```

It is possible, that you want to use `1%` or `10000%` instead (I don't know `$progress` input range).

Also: what the hell is `$color: $color`? According to SASS scope rules, it doesn't make any sense.